# How to change the color of Stack Navigator Options Right Header

Tags: react-native

I want to change the rightHeader color of the stack navigator options. When I applied styling it gave and error saying undefined is not an object. This is my code. How can I fix this?

I want to change the rightHeader color to blue. I use a touchable opacity here.

```
 static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: "Share To Feed",
    headerTitleStyle: {
      paddingLeft: "20%",
      paddingRight: "20%"
    },
    headerStyle: {
      paddingRight: 10,
      paddingLeft: 10
    },
    headerLeft: (
      <Icon
        name={"close"}
        size={30}
        onPress={() => {
          //this.props.navigation.navigate("comments");
        }}
      />
    ),
    headerRight: (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.headerRight}>
          <Text>Post</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  };
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  sharePostWrapper: {
    marginTop: 0,
    marginRight: 5,
    marginBottom: 5,
    marginLeft: 5,
    padding: 5,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "gray"
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    width: width - 20,
    height: 200
  },
  headerRight: {
    color: "blue"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're applying [style](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view-style-props.html#style) on the `View`, therefore it should be `backgroundColor` and not `color`

[`color`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#style) is specific to [`Text`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html) type of node elements